# dcc.Graph don't show Figure Factory object

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating a dashboard but I have problems with one Figure Factory object not displaying on the space designated by the dcc.Graph object.

Im building one figure like this:

[image: Figure]

But the figure that gets generated in the dash app is empy.

[image: Error]

```
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, 
    external_stylesheets= [bs],
    meta_tags= [{'name': 'viewport',
                 'content': 'width=device-width, inicial-scale=1.0'}]

)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(html.H1("Saberes", className= 'mb-4'),
                style={'margin-top':20, 'margin-botton': 10}, 
                width= 12),
                ], no_gutters=False, justify= 'center', align= 'center', className= 'h-50'
        ),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(html.Div('Selecciona la organizacion acompañante de la que quieras consultar datos'),
                style={'margin-top':20, 'margin-botton': 10},
                width= 12),
            ], no_gutters=False, justify= 'center', align= 'center', className= 'h-50'
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
                            id='org',
                            options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in datosBase.DG_ORG.org_ases_acomp.unique()],
                            value= init_value,
                            style={'margin-top':20, 'margin-botton': 5}
                            ),
                        width= 6
                ),
            ], no_gutters=False, justify= 'center', align= 'center'
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='tabla_dg',), #figure={}),
                        width= {'size': 6,  "offset": 0, 'order': 1},
                        style={'margin-top':20, 'margin-botton': 5}
                    ),
            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='linea_temp', figure={}),
                        width= {'size': 6,  "offset": 0, 'order': 2},
                        style={'margin-top':20, 'margin-botton': 5}
                        ), 
            ], no_gutters=False, justify= 'center', align= 'center'
        ),
    ], fluid= True, # Eliminar margenes en horizantales en el dash
       style={'backgroundColor': colores['bg']}
)

@app.callback(
    [Output("tabla_dg", "figure")],
    [Input("org", "value")]
)
def tabla_dg(org):

    # Tabla de datos generales
    df_org = datosBase.DG_ORG[datosBase.DG_ORG['org_ases_acomp'] == org]

    # Numero de estados en los que tiene presencia
    dg_org_est = rempl_selec_mult(df_org, 'estds_presen', 'id_org')
    estados_presencia = eval_literal(dg_org_est, 'estds_presen')
    estados_presencia = estados_presencia.explode('estds_presen')

    # Contar los estados en los que tienen presencia las organizaciones
    estados_ct = pd.DataFrame(estados_presencia.groupby('estds_presen')['id_org'].count())
    estados_ct.rename(columns= {'id_org':'conteo'}, inplace= True)

    # Contar cuanto sistemas de producion atienden
    # Separar elementos de las lista en una columna unica
    sist_prod = eval_literal(df_org, 'prod_sist_aten')
    sist_prod = sist_prod.explode('prod_sist_aten')

    # Agrupamos los datos para contar el numero de organizaciones por estado
    sist_prod_cnt = pd.DataFrame(sist_prod.groupby('prod_sist_aten')['id_org'].count())

    #Crear un nuevo df
    df_conteo_general = pd.DataFrame({
        'Total Socios': [df_org.num_soci.sum()],
        'Total Ha': [df_org.num_ha_org.sum()],
        'Num Orgs Socias': [len(df_org)],
        'Sist/Prod Atentidos': [len(sist_prod_cnt)],
        'Num Estados': [len(estados_presencia.estds_presen.unique())],
    })

    df_conteo_general = df_conteo_general.T.reset_index()
    df_conteo_general.rename(columns= {"index": "Datos Orgs Acompañadas", 0: "CONTEO"}, inplace= True)
    df_conteo_general['CONTEO'] = [int(i) for i in df_conteo_general['CONTEO']]

    # Creamos la figura de la tabla
    fig = ff.create_table(df_conteo_general)

    for i in range(len(fig.layout.annotations)):
        fig.layout.annotations[i].font.size = 11

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x= estados_ct.index,
        y= estados_ct.conteo,
        text= estados_ct.conteo,
        hovertemplate= 
            
            '<b><i>Conteo</i></b>: %{y}<br>',

        textposition= 'auto', # Posicion del texto en la figura
        orientation= 'v', # Orientacion del gráfico
        name= "Estados donde tienen presencia {}".format(org),
        marker= dict(color= '#CD7F32'),
        xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2'
    ))

    # Añadimos a la figura la gráfica
    fig.update_layout(
        font=dict(
            family="Arial",
            size= 10,
        ),
    margin = {'t':20, 'b':20},
    xaxis = {'domain': [0.01, 0.5],},
    xaxis2 = {'domain': [0.55, 0.99]},
    yaxis2 = {'anchor': 'x2', 'title': 'Goals'}
    )
    # Modificamos colores
    fig.layout.paper_bgcolor = colores['plot_bg']
    
    return fig
```